# Use Delphi to Find Special Drives

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-shell

I am trying to write a small program in Delphi 2007 to access files off of a portable USB drive whenever it is plugged in to a Windows 7 machine.  This drive does not show up as a standard drive letter though.  It appears under Portable Devices in Windows Explorer.  I have written the following code to enumerate all the items under 'Computer':

```
Procedure TfrmMain.ComputerChanged(Var Msg: TMessage);
Var
  Enum: IEnumIDList;
  Fetched: Longword;
  Item: PItemIDList;
  Path: String;
  Computer: IShellFolder;
  StrRet: TSTRRET;
Begin
  Status('Computer changed...  Checking folders.');
  fDesktop.BindToObject(fCompPidl, Nil, IID_IShellFolder, Computer);
  If Assigned(Computer) And
     (Computer.EnumObjects(Self.Handle, SHCONTF_FOLDERS, Enum) = NOERROR) Then
  Begin
    While (Enum.Next(1, Item, Fetched) = NOERROR) Do
    Begin
      FillChar(StrRet, SizeOf(StrRet), #0);
      Computer.GetDisplayNameOf(Item, SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR or SHGDN_NORMAL, StrRet);
      Path := StrRetToStr(StrRet, Item);
      Status(Path);
    End;
  End;
End;
```

(note: the Status procedure just outputs a message to a TMemo.)

This is called whenever my application is notified of a change by the Windows shell subsystem.  It enumerates all of the local drives and network drives but nothing else (iCloud Photos drive is missing as well).

Does anyone know how I can access the files on these virtual drives?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ahhhh... Wonderful.  Another full API to learn instead of just using the existing shell functions.  Well, once I learned about the Windows Portable Devices API, I found someone who has written a complete sample program doing exactly what I want.  Unfortunately, it is on Experts Exchange and you would need an account to see it.  For those that have one, check here: www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_28303837.html

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark this closed?

Comment: Post an answer yourself please, you already know more than me about it :).

Comment: Search for "Q_28303837 www.experts-exchange.com" via Google and you will be able to get to the answer. Someone has posted a program which is located here: http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/03_w12/840187/mtp10.zip

Comment: "Portable Devices" are definitely accessible via the shell namespace.  We use the Plasmatech controls, which don't use the PortableDevice APIs, and they're able to see them.

Comment: @NicholasRing: Yes, that is the same Experts Exchange article that I referenced in my comment above, thanks.

Comment: @CraigPeterson: I'm not sure that will work for me.  A) it's a commercial package and B) it looks like it just reproduces Windows Explorer.  Does it allow you to just access files without any of the GUI stuff at all?

Comment: @Caynadian IF you go via Google, the answer will be shown. If you don't, the answer will be hidden by EE.

Comment: @Caynadian: I wasn't recommending Plasmatech, just pointing out that the shell supports portable devices and you were doing something wrong.  I didn't have time to research it further at the time and I was hoping you wouldn't waste effort learning the WPD api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You more than likely aren't initializing COM correctly.  Your code will work as-is if you don't call [CoInitializeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or if you call it with a bad value, but the Portable Device drivers require apartment threading to work.

Based on your code, here's a sample app that works correctly and shows portable devices.  If you comment out the `CoInitializeEx`/`CoUninitialize` calls or pass in `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` instead it will still work, but it only shows the drives.

```
program ListMyComputer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ComObj, ShlObj, ShellApi, ShLwApi, ActiveX, Windows, SysUtils;

var
  Enum: IEnumIDList;
  Fetched: Longword;
  CompPidl, Item: PItemIDList;
  Path: PWideChar;
  Desktop, Computer: IShellFolder;
  StrRet: TSTRRET;
begin
  CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
  try
    WriteLn('Computer changed...  Checking folders.');
    SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop);
    SHGetFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_DRIVES, 0, 0, CompPidl);
    Desktop.BindToObject(CompPidl, Nil, IID_IShellFolder, Computer);
    CoTaskMemFree(CompPidl);
    If Assigned(Computer) And
       (Computer.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_FOLDERS, Enum) = NOERROR) Then
    Begin
      While (Enum.Next(1, Item, Fetched) = NOERROR) Do
      Begin
        FillChar(StrRet, SizeOf(StrRet), #0);
        Computer.GetDisplayNameOf(Item, SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR or SHGDN_NORMAL, StrRet);
        StrRetToStr(@StrRet, Item, Path);
        WriteLn(Path);
        CoTaskMemFree(Path);
      End;
    End;
    WriteLn('Enumeration complete');
    ReadLn;
  finally
    CoUninitialize
  end;
end.
```

Comment: @Ken: D'oh! Fixed. My original version just leaked everything, and I tried throwing that in when I was cleaning it up to post.

Comment: No problem. I upvoted it anyway because with the minor fix it worked. I just figured I'd mention it. :-)

Comment: @CraigPeterson: Cool! Thanks.  I did think it weird that the normal shell controls wouldn't see portable devices.  I never thought about the initialization stuff because everything worked without it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SertacAkyuz for pointing out the need to use Windows Portable Device API which lead me to [this Experts Exchange question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_28303837.html) discussing the same thing.  [Sinisa Vuk](http://rdsrc.us/lhshJT) supplied an awesome code example to answer that question which I have linked (it's too long to embed) here with permission: http://pastebin.com/0hSWv5pE