# Detect when an iPhone is connected via USB and get the device path in Windows using Delphi XE2

Tags: iphone, delphi, usb, delphi-xe2

I am trying to detect when USB devices are connected to my computer,
and I have succeeded thanks to various posts online,
especially the post in the following link: http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200511/0511143247.html

This works very well with storage devices such as USB Flash Memory,
but how do I detect when for instance an iPhone is connected and how
do I determine its Explorer path so that I can scan through its photo content?

Comment: What kind of values is `WM_DEVICECHANGE` giving you when an iPhone is plugged in? Instead of asking what to do, you could show what it is actually giving you and then ask what it means. For instance, when `WM_DEVICECHANGE` reports `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` in its wParam, what `dbch_devicetype` is being reported by the `DEV_BROADCAST_HDR` in the `lParam`? If the device type is `DBT_DEVTYP_OEM`, then type-cast the lParam to `DEV_BROADCAST_OEM`, it might give you something useful to detect iPhone devices.

Comment: I am investigating my problem and my goals, the iPhone is presented by Windows as a Portable Device. I found the following Question which solves the listing/enumuration of Portable devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962222/use-delphi-to-find-special-drives

Comment: The code example in that question successfully lists the iPhone as a Portable Device from within the Delphi application, now I just need to figure out how to get the proper path for the iPhone

Comment: Why do you need the device path? What are you going to do with it? The device is not part of the filesystem. If you are just trying to retrieve a file from the device, or put a file onto the device, use the `IPortableDeviceContent` interface instead: [Transferring an Image or Music File to the Device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388994.aspx), [Transferring Content from the Device to a PC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388996.aspx)

Comment: You are right @RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLebeau all lParam of DEV_BROADCAST_OEM says is 5, I guess it means $0005, but I cant find it in microsofts page.

Comment: The `lParam` itself cannot be 5, as it is a pointer to a `DEV_BROADCAST_HDR` record. Did you check to make sure that `PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(lParam).dbco_devicetype` is `DBT_DEVTYP_OEM`? If it is, then what values are `PDEV_BROADCAST_OEM(lParam).dbco_identifier` and `PDEV_BROADCAST_OEM(lParam).dbco_suppfunc`?  Are you saying they are both 5?  You might also need to use `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()` or related function to get detailed device information in order to identify it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is not DBT_DEVTYP_OEM

I found some usable code at on this blog: http://nitemsg.blogspot.se/2011/01/heres-unit-written-in-delphi-7-that-you.html

Comment: Some of that code allows me to extract a friendly name of the connected device, however I am looking in to a Microsoft article which I am trying to use to extract more information about the device: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363264(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have converted some of that code to Delphi so I can get the value value of MediaInfoCount and  DeviceType, but whatever is stored in MediaInfo[1] is kind unknown to me, maybe you could help if we go in to chat mode?